# How to read txt file with number and changing it to a NxN matrix?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, matrix

I'm finding the distance between cities. The text document contains the distances between all the cities we are going to visit. If there are N cities, then the text document contains an NxN array of float numbers, where element (i,j) is the distance from city i to city j . How can I convert it to a NxN matrix with a for loops?

I have made the NxN matrix with only 0's and I have found the first line.

For example here is the file 'small_distances.txt':

0.0 2.0 2.23606797749979 4.47213595499958 5.385164807134504

2.0 0.0 2.23606797749979 4.0 3.605551275463989

2.23606797749979 2.23606797749979 0.0 2.23606797749979 4.0

4.47213595499958 4.0 2.23606797749979 0.0 3.605551275463989

5.385164807134504 3.605551275463989 4.0 3.605551275463989 0.0

```
def create_2_list(rows,columns): 
    the_2d_list = []
    for i in range(rows):
        current_row = []
        for j in range(columns):
            current_row.append(0)
        the_2d_list.append(current_row)
    return the_2d_list

def print_2d_list(the_list):
    for i in range(len(the_list)):
        for j in range(len(the_list[i])):
            print(the_list[i][j], end=' ')
        print()

def read_line_in_txt(file):
    file = open(filename,'r')
    line = file.readline()
    t = line.split()

    return t

filename = 'small_distances.txt'
the_file = open(filename,'r')
the_data = the_file.readlines()

the_file.close()

n_cities = len(the_data)

distances = create_2_list(n_cities,n_cities)
print_2d_list(distances)
print('---------------------------')
line = read_line_in_txt(the_data)
print(line)
 print('---------------------------')
```

I'm expecting this:
`0.0 2.0 2.23606797749979 4.47213595499958 5.385164807134504 2.0 0.0 2.23606797749979 4.0 3.605551275463989                                  2.23606797749979 2.23606797749979 0.0 2.23606797749979 4.0   4.47213595499958 4.0 2.23606797749979 0.0 3.605551275463989                                      5.385164807134504 3.605551275463989 4.0 3.605551275463989 0.0`

```
# Line one in .txt
t = '0.0 2.0 2.23606797749979 4.47213595499958 5.385164807134504'
t.split()
->['0.0', '2.0', '2.23606797749979', '4.47213595499958', '5.385164807134504']
#  City1- City2-  City3-              City4-              City-5
# The distance between cities

len(t.split())
->5
# With this information you can make another two-dimensional for-loop
# and make a matrix for the distances
```

Comment: Hi, note that the code you added isn't in a code block. Therefore it's difficult to understand it. See this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: It's hard to understand how your output should look like. Why don't you just do `with open("small_distances.txt", "r") as file: matrix = [list(map(float, line.split())) for line in file]`?

Comment: I'm doing a Traveling Salesman Problem and I have to do this first: Write a program that reads the name of a text document. The text document contains the distances between all the cities we are going to visit. If there are N cities, then the text document contains an NxN array of float numbers, where element (i,j) is the distance from city i to city j.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the problem with your question. It doesn't matter on what kind of problem you are exactly working on: as long as the input and expected output isn't clearly presented in the question, it is hard to help. Your input isn't formatted at all (e.g. are the blank lines actually there, ...?). Your expected output is a mess that doesn't seem to have any structure.

Comment: Okey, yeah I understand you. My teacher gave us this information:  `# Line one in .txt
t = '0.0 2.0 2.23606797749979 4.47213595499958 5.385164807134504'
t.split()
->['0.0', '2.0', '2.23606797749979', '4.47213595499958', '5.385164807134504']
#  City1- City2-  City3-              City4-              City-5
# The distance between cities

len(t.split())
->5
# With this information you can make another two-dimensional for-loop
# and make a matrix for the distances`

Comment: This is more clear in the question at the **bottom**

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
matrix = genfromtxt("small_distances.txt").tolist()
print(matrix)
```

which produces:

```
[[0.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 4.47213595499958, 5.385164807134504], [2.0, 0.0, 2.23606797749979, 4.0, 3.605551275463989], [2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 0.0, 2.23606797749979, 4.0], [4.47213595499958, 4.0, 2.23606797749979, 0.0, 3.605551275463989], [5.385164807134504, 3.605551275463989, 4.0, 3.605551275463989, 0.0]]
```

Comment: I can't use numpy...

Answer (score 0):

So currently, your lines:

```
filename = 'small_distances.txt'
the_file = open(filename,'r')
the_data = the_file.readlines()
the_file.close()
```

will leave you with a `list` variable called `the_data`. If you print this out, you should see that `the_data` is a list with 5 entries, each being a string containing one line from the file (it might contain 6 entries if there was a newline at the end of the file).

You can loop through each of these lines to generate a list of lists (your NxN matrix) with e.g.,

```py
distances = []  # create empty list
for line in the_data:
    d = []  # empty list to contain each item in the line
    for dist in line.split():  # split the line on whitespace
        d.append(float(dist))  # convert the from a string to a number with float and append to d
    distances.append(d)  # append that line into distances
```

This should give the array you want. This could be done more compactly with list comprehension using:

```py
distance = [[float(dist) for dist in line.split()] for line in the_data]
```

If your data file does contain a new line at the end, you can check for this by ignoring lines that have zero length, e.g.,:

```py
for line in the_data:
    d = []  # empty list to contain each item in the line
    if len(line.strip()) > 0:  # only use lines that contain characters
        for dist in line.split():  # split the line on whitespace
            d.append(float(dist))  # convert the from a string to a number with float and append to d
        distances.append(d)  # append that line into distances
```

Comment: But I don't a NxN matrix out of this for-loop do I?

Comment: I get this: `[[0.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 4.47213595499958, 5.385164807134504], [2.0, 0.0, 2.23606797749979, 4.0, 3.605551275463989], [2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 0.0, 2.23606797749979, 4.0], [4.47213595499958, 4.0, 2.23606797749979, 0.0, 3.605551275463989], [5.385164807134504, 3.605551275463989, 4.0, 3.605551275463989, 0.0]]`

Comment: am I missing something?

Comment: @John How is that **not** a 5x5 matrix? (This is similiar to the solution I've proposed in a comment which gives you the exact same output.)

Comment: Sry, I see it now. But does your solution and his relate to the function create_2_list() ? or just completely new script.

Comment: Your `create_2_lists` function currently will create a list of 5 sublists lists, each containing 5 zeros.  This answer can replace that function as you don't need to create the lists with zeros first, you can just make it out of the data straight away. You could turn my answer into a function, by wrapping it with, e.g., `def create_matrix(the_data):` at the start and `return distances` at the end and then calling `distances = create_matrix(the_data)`.

Comment: Ait, thanks... This method is much shorter than what the teacher showed us :)